# Show multiple currencies, but transact in base currency

Tags: currency, multicurrency, currency-rates

I'm sure I'm missing something obvious, but for my store I need customers to be able to see products in different prices (USD, EUR etc), but all transactions need to take place in GBP.

Is there a way to configure this in Magento?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This happens by default - you have a base currency on which everything is configured and setup (product prices etc) and the other currencies the prices for which are calculated based on the current currency rate between the base.  When an order is put through figures are stored against the order for all prices in both base and sale currency.